# GridView and Model Binding

Tags: asp.net, gridview, model-binding

How do we use strongly-typed Model Binding with `GridView`'s `BoundField`? The `DataField` attribute of `BoundField` seems to take a string value only, unlike `FormView` where I can use the proper Model Binding syntax like `Prop="<%# MyFieldName %>"`. Is `TemplateField` my only option here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any future reader, `TemplateField` is your only choice if you want to take advantage of strongly-typed binding and intellisense etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but still I have created a small app like this.

Here is gridview in aspx page.

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdEmployee" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ModelType="WebApplication1.Employee">
       <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
       </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

Now I have created Employee class like following.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and in page_load event of asp.net I am writing this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Employee> employees=new List<Employee>();
        Employee employee=new Employee{Age = 33,Name = "Jalpesh Vadgama"};
        employees.Add(employee);

        employee = new Employee { Age = 30, Name = "Vishal Vadgama" };
        employees.Add(employee);

        grdEmployee.DataSource = employees;
        grdEmployee.DataBind();
    }
```

and it's works. For two way binding you need to use template control with bindItem.

Reference- http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-4-5-strongly-typed-data-controls-model-binding/

Comment: The code you have provided is not model binding. It is the pure old way of doing things. The link you found however is correct model binding; not sure if you got a chance to go through it or not. But the precise problem is that `DataField` attribute in your code takes string values like 'Age' and 'Name', which doesn't have the benefits of strongly-typed model binding like intellisense etc. `TemplateField` however does support model binding, as shown in the article as well. I'm trying to do the same thing with `BoundField`.

Comment: You can not bind it with boundfield